# No such file or directory: Python CSV

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm trying to create a csv file into a different directory. While running the code on development server it works fine, but on production, it raises an error that `No such file or directory:`

Following is my code:-

```
def write_operation(filename,data):
    with open("./static/" + filename, "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(data)

@csrf_exempt
def download_data(request):

    if request.POST.has_key('download_data'):
        start_date = str(request.POST['start_date']).replace('/','-')
        end_date = str(request.POST['end_date']).replace('/','-')

        start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")


        data.insert(0,('Barcode','Weight', 'Length','Breadth','Height'))
        write_operation('data.csv',data)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps('Success'),content_type = "application/json")
    ctx = {}
    return render(request, 'dummy/download_data.html', ctx)
```

The error that I receive is :-

`Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/data.csv'`

Here is my directory structure:-

```
├── modules
|   ├── dummy
│   │   └── views.py
├── static
```

Comment: Are you positive you are running it from the right directory level? That looks like a relative path. (I'm assuming you double checked that the file is there)

Comment: The file is there. Just to check , I created a file manually. Tried `localhost:8000/static/data.csv`, it gets open (on the production as well), but still unable to write the data via the code.

Comment: Just double-checking ... it happens to the best of us.

Comment: Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: I am unfortunately not very familiar with this ... so no, not really.  Sorry.  You'll have to wait for somebody to see it who knows django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use full path to prevent these errors. For example, your project folder `/home/project-name/`. You can define a constant to your config and set your project home folder as `base_dir`. Then change your code the following:

```
def write_operation(filename,data):
    with open(config.base_dir + "static/" + filename, "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(data)
```

Edit: 
I missed the script related with the django. Above solution is a general solution for python. Django version is almost the same.

Add your settings.py file the following lines

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

And change your method with following:

```
from django.conf import settings
...

def write_operation(filename,data):
with open(settings.BASE_DIR + "static/" + filename, "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

In fact, both of them is the same on the base.

Comment: Worked well. But whats wrong with the relative path. and production-development difference???

Comment: I think, when you work on development, you go to the project directory and run the script with `python manage.py runserver`. On production, you may use `python /path-the-directory/.../manage.py runserver`. Or you may use different operating system with production and development.

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding such a problem just use BASE_DIR value, that is initialized and assigned in your project settings.py

As it is said in official documentation:

> Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)